# Quad monitors work as mirror displays but not as extended

Tags: ati, 14.04, multiple-monitors, display, radeon

So i gave up on fglrx driver due to unsupported GPUs now i'm on regular radeon drivers with 4 monitors on 14.04. I got them all to work perfectly fine with `All Settings/Displays mirror mode` but when if i try to uncheck Mirrored Display i get "The selected configuration for displays could not be applied/could not set the configuration for CRTC 64" pop up error and either both monitors 3&4 just freeze with last image, or 3 works but 4 just goes black with no signal

```
$ sudo lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT] [1002:9588]
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT] [1002:9588]
```

and

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fe6e0000-fe6effff ioport:a000(size=256) memory:fe6c0000-fe6dffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV630 XT [Radeon HD 2600 XT]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:fe9e0000-fe9effff ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe9c0000-fe9dffff
```

more info

```
$ sudo xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 7680 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-0 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1200      60.0*+
   1600x1200      60.0  
...more resolutions...
DIN disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
...more resolutions...
DVI-1-2 connected 1920x1080+3840+0 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9     30.0     30.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
...more resolutions...
DIN-1-1 disconnected
DVI-1-3 connected 1920x1080+5760+0 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   50.0     59.9     30.0     30.0  
   1920x1080i     60.1     50.0     60.0  
...more resolutions...
  1920x1080 (0x45)  148.5MHz
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
...more resolutions...
```

**Edit**

ATI card with radeon driver, anyone?

Comment: Probable dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/397966

Comment: Looks like a bug. Suggest you ask on the Nouveau mailing list to confirm.

Comment: were you able to solve your problem, I'm having a similar issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a bug (perhaps related to CRTC sharing). AMD's open source GPU driver team are, from what I've heard, responsive to bug reports. You can find the bug tracker and mailing lists at http://wiki.x.org/wiki/radeon/ - they also have an IRC channel #radeon on irc.freenode.net for radeon users and developers. I just saw a comment today about one of their open source developers [fixing a bug in 15 minutes](http://richg42.blogspot.com/2014/05/the-truth-on-opengl-driver-quality.html?showComment=1399921776400#c553646987795055150) after it was reported on the IRC channel, so I'd recommend trying that or the mailing lists.