# ERROR : could not set the configuration for CRTC 64

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors, nvidia-prime

I was working on Ubuntu 12.04 doing my opengl programming and the problem was that I needed to use nvidia prime (laptop here), then backport it to dual monitor which was not supported.

I got tired of not using the second monitor so  that I have I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in another partition (where nvidia prime should be fully supported).
Everything works fine as I can compile my opengl stuff etc. Thus, I receive below error when I start from reboot:

```
could not set the configuration for CRTC 64
```

And then the monitors appears to be finicky. Although, I can reset the monitor every time I log-in, I would rater fix it for once. The only thing I found online was to delete the monitor `.xml` which doesn’t resolve anything but removes the config.

Any advise to overcome this issue?

**PS** : I can set the monitor no problem from Screen setting , but if I open nvidia settings it shows only one monitor of size  3840x1080 rather then two 1920x1080.

Comment: Did you check http://askubuntu.com/questions/397966/nouveau-quad-monitors-dual-gpu-error-could-not-set-the-configuration-for-crtc-6?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nouveau quad monitors dual-GPU error: could not set the configuration for CRTC 64](http://askubuntu.com/questions/397966/nouveau-quad-monitors-dual-gpu-error-could-not-set-the-configuration-for-crtc-6)

Answer (score 1):

Running Ubuntu 14.04 with a ATI Radeon card. I did this to get rid of this issue. Follow the steps bellow:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get --reinstall install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates
sudo reboot
```