# Could not switch the monitor configuration could not set the configuration for CRTC 64

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have ubuntu 15.04 whenever I connect the HDMI, it just doesnt work, I get the error: 
Could not switch the monitor configuration could not set the configuration for CRTC 64

Nvidia driver is already installed but is it configuration? everything works fine except this.

I tried this sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg but nothing happens.

Comment: possibly related: [ERROR : could not set the configuration for CRTC 64](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486844/error-could-not-set-the-configuration-for-crtc-64)