# Could not set the configuration for crtc 64 (15.04)

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

Sometimes when I attach an second LCD monitor (iiyama ProLite E2407HDSV)

[Specs:](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/673627/Iiyama-Prolite-E2407hds.html#manual)

```
Native resolution   Full HD 1080p, 1920 x 1080 ( 2.1 megapixel)
Horizontal sync 30-81 KHz
Vertical sync 56-75 Hz
```

to my Asus N56J laptop

[Display Specs:](http://www.kmart.com/asus-n56j-15.6inch-notebook-with-intel-core-i7/p-020V007360940000P)

```
15.6" IPS 1920 x 1080 ( Full HD )
```

and I try to extend my laptop monitor with the LCD I get the error:

```
could not set the configuration for crtc 64
```

After a few tries it does work and the error is gone. Also when I go to my display settings I get a transparent window, like so:

[image]

Also the following additional drivers are installed:

[image]

`myuser@my-laptop:~$ xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3520 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080      60.1*+   59.9  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
HDMI1 disconnected
VGA1 connected 1600x1200+1920+0 521mm x 293mm
   1600x1200      60.0* 
   1680x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     70.1     60.0  
   832x624        74.6  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3     56.2  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected
```

`myuser@my-laptop:~$ sudo lshw -c video`:

```
[sudo] password for myuser: 
  *-display               
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 840M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:42 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:39 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

`myuser@my-laptop:~$ lspci | grep VGA`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06
```

`myuser@my-laptop:~$ uname -r`:

```
3.19.0-30-generic
```

`myuser@my-laptop:~$ X -version`:

```
X.Org X Server 1.17.1
Release Date: 2015-02-10
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 3.19.0-28-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux mva-laptop 3.19.0-30-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 21 20:58:04 UTC 2015 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-30-generic root=UUID=a1d7434a-6c0f-4117-8d2f-1e32f902475f ro quiet splash
Build Date: 11 September 2015  10:30:58AM
xorg-server 2:1.17.1-0ubuntu3.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
```

Comment: possibly related: [ERROR : could not set the configuration for CRTC 64](http://askubuntu.com/questions/486844/error-could-not-set-the-configuration-for-crtc-64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the specifications for your external screen, I recommend that you change the settings to match it's **native resolution**. Based on your xrandr output you've got it configured for 1600x1200 @ 60 Hz One of the things the manufacturer suggests doing ([in the manual](http://www.manualmonitor.com/manuals/iiyama/Iiyama_ProLite_E2407HDS-1.pdf)) before contacting the iiyama information line is to check "if the correct **native resolution** has been selected via 'Display Properties".

To set things up to use the manufacturers recommended resolution you would generate a modeline with `cvt`. Since this is a TFT display and I can't find any indication to the contrary I'm using a refresh rate of 60 to generate the modeline.

So you'd generate the modeline with:

`cvt 1920 1080 60`
Which results in output similar to this:

```
1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then you would apply the modeline with xrandr with:

`xrandr --newmode` ***Everything*** After Modeline from the cvt output
*including the quotes* and then

`xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00`

Where VGA1 is the port your display is connected to and the remainder of the line is everything between quotes from the cvt output

Sources:

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/673627/Iiyama-Prolite-E2407hds.html#manual

http://www.kmart.com/asus-n56j-15.6inch-notebook-with-intel-core-i7/p-020V007360940000P

http://www.manualmonitor.com/manuals/iiyama/Iiyama_ProLite_E2407HDS-1.pdf

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaResolutionXorgConf

[How to set a custom resolution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was as simple as opening **`Driver Manager`** from the start menu and then picking a different driver and rebooting!

[image]

Both `nvidia-460` and `nvidia-495` produced the CRTC error message for me while `nvidia-470` and `nouveau` worked just fine (although the nvidia is considered better). So try both "recommended" and the "open-source" driver for your system.

PS: The `Driver Manager` would not let me select options at first, so I needed to run:

```
sudo apt install packagekit*
```